# Rent and Housing Prices by Postal Code / Local Authority Code

Tags: data-request, europe, postal-code, real-estate

I am looking for databases that provide information on the development of mean / median house prices and rents in European countries, particularly for UK, NL, CH und SE (rental market data). Do any of you have an idea where I can find something helpful, be it for free or not. I would very much appreciate your help!